# C symbolic constant + strcture

Tags: c, constants, structure

Given the following snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 15

typedef struct{
  int touchdowns;
  int interceptions;
  int tackles[MAX_SIZE + 1];        //this is the line in question
}stats;
```

The question posed to me was, "Why does this line [denoted above] add 1 to the possible number of tackles?"

**----NOT why would one want too, but how/why does it work. Why is it valid code in otherwords, not necessarily valid logic.     -Clarification**

I'm unsure of how to answer this question in detail. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAX_SIZE is replaced by 100 when code is compiled and the line becomes

```
int tackles[100 + 1];
```

which is the same as

```
int tackles[101];
```

From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/):

To define preprocessor macros we can use #define. Its format is:

```
#define identifier replacement
```

When the preprocessor encounters this directive, it replaces any occurrence of identifier in the rest of the code by replacement. This replacement can be an expression, a statement, a block or simply anything. The preprocessor does not understand C++, it simply replaces any occurrence of identifier by replacement.

```
#define TABLE_SIZE 100
int table1[TABLE_SIZE];
int table2[TABLE_SIZE];
```

After the preprocessor has replaced TABLE_SIZE, the code becomes equivalent to:

```
int table1[100];
int table2[100];
```

Comment: I believe that is what I put on the exam in question, but I was marked off.

Comment: Ok thanks, I believe that is basically exactly what I put... I said something like "when an instance of the structure is created, the symbolic constant will have been replaced by the number 100, therefore, 100 + 1 is a valid operation. Well thanks for your help.

Comment: >>When an instance of the structure is created, the symbolic...<< is wrong, the MAX_SIZE is replaced just before the compilation of the code.

Comment: "will have been" implies what you just said.

Answer (score 2):

As Armin pointed out, the token `MAX_SIZE` is replaced by the preprocessor. But for clarification, that's not why it works/compiles in the end. The actual requirement for this to compile is, that the array size is a *constant integral expression*, which applies to the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `tackles` is an array terminated by a terminator value (such as -1), similar how C strings are terminated by the null character. Note how the structure has no member denoting the number of tackles.

Comment: Consider my recent clairifaction. the question is concerned with why is this valid code, not logic. Sorry if I was confusing.

Comment: @Vlad In that case I don't understand the question at all — code doesn't need a *reason* to be valid. But if I were to guess, [Sam's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15045136/1600898) might be the closest to what the interviewer was aiming at.